# Reactjs-tables. How to join multiple values into 1 cell?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using [react-table](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table) but I have 2 values that I want to join into one cell. Does anyone know how to do this?

Say I have this sample code, right now it has "name" which as the first and last name combined.

What happens if in my db I have it separate by first name and last. How could I join them together in the ui here(I know I could do this at the db level but this just an example)

```
import ReactTable from 'react-table'

render() {
  const data = [{
    name: 'Tanner Linsley',
    age: 26,
    friend: {
      name: 'Jason Maurer',
      age: 23,
    }
  },{
    ...
  }]

  const columns = [{
    Header: 'Name',
    accessor: 'name' // String-based value accessors!
  }, {
    Header: 'Age',
    accessor: 'age',
    Cell: props => <span className='number'>{props.value}</span> // Custom cell components!
  }, {
    id: 'friendName', // Required because our accessor is not a string
    Header: 'Friend Name',
    accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
  }, {
    Header: props => <span>Friend Age</span>, // Custom header components!
    accessor: 'friend.age'
  }]

  <ReactTable
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
  />
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

would this work?

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: 'Full Name',
    accessor: d => `${d.firstName} ${d.lastName}`
  }
]
```

Comment: Yea that will work for that use case, but if I have say 2 boolean fields and I want to use the "cell property" as shown in the example and do some custom changes then it's not 100% idea as "value" would look like "false false" which would require me to parse it out somehow, which maybe the only way to get it to work.

Comment: ah you can always do some conditional like `accessor: d => ${d.firstBool ? 'Yes': 'No'} ${d.secondBool ? 'Render' : ' ' }` or `accessor: d => ${d.firstBool || 'Fallback value'} ${d.secondBool || 'Default value' }`

Comment: You need to add id if you want to have sorting or filtering and you need to indicate this works for react-tables v6

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to sort by one of the values

```
{
    Header: "Price",
    accessor : "unit_price", // matters for grouping and sorting
    Cell     : props => <span>
      {props.original.currency} {Numeral(props.original.unit_price).format('0,0.00')}
    </span>
  },
```